# Redirect page after checking password

Tags: javascript, redirect, button, google-apps-script, hyperlink

I use the *userClicked()* in code.gs of my google apps script to save some data if the user password in login.html is correct.
How can I redirect the user to page.html after saving data in line #18?
I want to redirect only if the password is correct. So I can't use simple  on the login page.

[Code.gs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcwzP.jpg)
[login.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VYmD.jpg)

**code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (!e.parameters.v){
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("login").evaluate();
  }
  else {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameters['v']).evaluate();
  }  
}

function userClicked(userInfo){
  if (userInfo.userPassword && userInfo.userPassword == userInfo.dbPassword){

    /* save page data in a google spreadsheet */
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OU6y0Iid5r2xGcfxZpUqGzZjZo8Gz7rALkYcajCslN8");      // calls "DB_" spreadsheet 
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");    
    var lastRow = ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow();  // get last row of column A
    var lastRow1 = lastRow + 1;    
    ws.getRange("A"+ lastRow1 +":D"+ lastRow1).setValues([[new Date(), userInfo.userName, userInfo.userPassword, userInfo.dbPassword ]]);

  }
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function lookup(pass){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1gBo8UrCpqtQ5Rf67HCriEDRhJeQuhvPZ1vebeTHndt0");      // calls "Therapists" spreadsheet 
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Therapists");
  var data = ws.getRange(1, 4, ws.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();
  var therapistsList =  data.map(function(r){ return r[0];});
  var passwordsList =  data.map(function(r){ return r[1];});
  var position = therapistsList.indexOf(pass);  
  if (position > -1){
    return passwordsList[position];
  }
  else {
    return 'Not Found!';
  }
}
```

**Login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <?!= include("css"); ?>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="container">

      <p>Login</p>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s3">
          <input id="username" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s3">
          <input disabled id="dbPass" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="dbPass">Database Pass</label>
        </div>

      </div><!-- row -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s3">
          <input id="userPass" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="userPass">Password</label>
        </div>
      </div><!-- row -->

       <div class="row">
         <button id="btn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small blue accent-4"><i class="material-icons left">play_arrow</i>submit</button>
       </div>

    </div> <!-- Container -->

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <?!= include("js_"); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `js_` is missing.

Comment: Did @Lakurwan answer solved your problem. Could you accept it if that was the case?

Answer (score 0):

add  tag and surround inside all your input field and other elements that take values from user.use return attribute with your function name. Return attribute does is; if your function returns true you can direct return false, you can't redirect

Ex:

```
 <form onsubmit="return productsvalidationform();" method="POST" action="AddProductServlet">
         <div class="form-group">                                                          
              <label>Product Name</label><br> <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="ProductName" placeholder="productname" id="productname">

         </div>                     

    </form>
```

productsvalidationform(); is the function,This function return true or false.If true we can be redirected to AddProductServlet.In the form tag, include action attribute that describes where you want to go.